# Excel VBA creating index according to number of dots

Tags: vba, excel

Basically, I am trying to convert "=LEN(C5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C5;".";""))+1" excel formula to be applicable for all cells as an embedded process in one of the macros. However when I run through the code, it does not show any value of the cells. The column is set to "General" format so that shouldn't be an issue. Any ideas on how to get the value on the cells?

```
For i = 3 To i = 10000
    Cells(i, 4).Value = Len(Cells(i, 3).Value) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(i, 3).Value, ".", "")) + 1
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
For i = 3 To i = 10000
```

To

```
For i = 3 To 10000
```

Comment: Silly me. Monday syndrome is a struggle. Thanks.